# FileSystemWatcher Not Observing Changes in Program Files (x86) Folder

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I'm trying to write a simple C# service to watch a folder and notify my app when that folder is updated. I found some great examples using FileSystemWatcher, but it does not work at all when I set the path to a folder beneath c:\Program Files (x86).

My code works fine when I set the path to other folders. I thought perhaps it was failing to read the path because of the parenthesis in the name. I tried naming a folder in root of C drive and used parenthesis and that did not work either. I'm not sure what exactly the issue is here or how to workaround it. Is it a permissions issue? Is there some way to escape characters in the path even though they are technically "legal"?

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
            {
                this.watchReflectAssetFolder = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher();
                ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.watchReflectAssetFolder)).BeginInit();
                // 
                // watchReflectAssetFolder
                // 
                this.watchReflectAssetFolder.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                this.watchReflectAssetFolder.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
                this.watchReflectAssetFolder.Path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Reflect Systems\\ReflectDistributor\\Cache\\WEBCASTS";
                this.watchReflectAssetFolder.Changed += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(this.watchReflectAssetFolder_Changed);
                // 
                // LevisAssetCopyService
                // 
                this.ServiceName = "LevisAssetCopyService";
                ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.watchReflectAssetFolder)).EndInit();

            }
 private void watchReflectAssetFolder_Changed(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            string ChangeType = e.ChangeType.ToString();

            //write a log entry for the appropriate changetype. 
            levisLog.WriteEntry("File Watch Type: " + ChangeType);

            if (ChangeType == "Created")
            {
                levisLog.WriteEntry("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.Name + " Created");
            }
            else if (ChangeType == "Deleted")
            {
                levisLog.WriteEntry("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.Name + " Deleted");
            }
            else if (ChangeType == "Changed")
            {
                levisLog.WriteEntry("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.Name + " Changed");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried to run your application as administrator to be sure that it's not because of permissions?

Comment: This is not a folder that programs can normally access to create, delete or change files.  UAC prevents that.  So what you see is entirely expected.

Comment: Plus, you need to set the watch type flags